# Find duplicates in a collection of lists

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, dictionary

If I have a dictionary containing 2 or more lists, how can I quickly find shared items between these lists and add these shared items to a list external to the dictionary?

For example:

list1:

- eng;English
- lir;Liberian English

list2:

- eng;English
- bav;Vengo

list3:

- lat;Latin

extList:

- eng;English

This shared item is then removed from the lists inside the dictionary.
I have added `list3` to show that a superfluous item may be ignored, and that I have specified 2 or more lists.

Comment: `eng;English` isn't shared between all lists anymore. Should it still be removed? Can one list contain the same item twice?

Comment: One list cannot contain the same item twice. However, if an item is shared between 2 or more lists it must be added to the extList and removed from the old lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have a list of lists (or a dictionary, which would add a Key):

```
List<List<string>> lists = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string> {"Hello", "World", "7"},
    new List<string> {"Hello", "7", "Person"},
    new List<string> {"7", "7", "Hello"}
};
```

You can find items that are present in *all* lists:

```
List<string> extList = lists.Cast<IEnumerable<string>>()
                            .Aggregate((a, b) => a.Intersect(b)).ToList();
```

If you want to get strings that are common to just a few lists, you can use:

```
var counts = from str in lists.SelectMany(list => list)
             group str by str into g
             where g.Count() > 1
             select new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

You can drop the last line if you don't care how many times each word appears. Note that this will not tell you in which list the word is.

Comment: This solution will find elements that are common to multiple lists *or* show up in a single list multiple times.

Comment: @Gabe - True. I've asked if that's a problem and it wasn't according to the OP. Either way, you can easily fix it with `.SelectMany(list => list.Distinct())`.

Comment: I just wanted to make that clear for all future visitors. Also, it may not matter to the OP, but a much better way to write `g.Count() > 1` is with `g.Skip(1).Any()`. Or you could use `let` to store the value of `Count()` so you don't have to compute it twice.

Answer (score 8):

As I understand you have two lists and need to find intersection between those lists and add this intersection to the third list:

```
var list1 = new[] { "eng;English", "lir;Liberian", "English" };
var list2 = new[] { "eng;English", "bav;Vengo", "English" };

extList.AddRange(list1.Intersect(list2));
```

Comment: @Gabe - the input structure was not clear from the question. I based my answer on the sample data, which originally showed two lists.

Comment: "2 or more lists" seems pretty clear to me. How would you write it to be clearer than that?

Comment: @Gabe - sounds like nitpicking... To make it clear I would specify that the number of lists is variable. I didn't know that it is. I thought that the list number is constant, and thought that if you know how to intersect two lists, you would add list3 and list4 for intersection if needed.

Comment: The OP specifies "I have a dictionary containing 2 or more lists" and my answer has a function that takes a dictionary containing 2 or more lists (actually any number). I don't see what your last comment is saying.

Comment: @Gabe - about my last comment - I apologize, didn't notice `Dictionary`. About your point that question was clear enough. I can also apologize that I misunderstood the question, although still think there was the way to make question clearer. Is this what you wanted me to do?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that will take a dictionary, remove any string that is in more than one list in the dictionary, and return the list of strings it removed:

```
static List<string> FindAndRemoveDuplicates(Dictionary<string, List<string>> data)
{
    // find duplicates
    var dupes = new HashSet<string>(
                    from list1 in data.Values
                    from list2 in data.Values
                    where list1 != list2
                    from item in list1.Intersect(list2)
                    select item);
    // remove dupes from lists in the dictionary
    foreach (var list in data.Values)
        list.RemoveAll(str => dupes.Contains(str));
    // return a list of the duplicates
    return dupes.ToList();
}
```